# Android Listview and image decoding

Tags: android, image, parsing, listview, decoding

```
        try
        {
            if(json.getString(KEY_SUCESS)!=null)
            {
                String res=json.getString(KEY_SUCESS);
                if(Integer.parseInt(res)==1)
                {
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    name=json_user.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String image=json_user.getString(KEY_PHOTO);

                    map.put(KEY_NAME, name);

                    map.put(KEY_PHOTO, image);

                    List.add(map);


                }
            }
```

The photo is an String which is encoded in `base64` and i want to decode it and add to the map created but it take two string value and if i create a new map it would not add to that list view that i have created ,
what i have to do is to decode the string image to set it to a `ImageView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show where your map is defined, but you get to choose what type of objects its key/value pair is.

It sounds like you want to take the string, decode into a bitmap and then store that into the map.

Define the map this way:

```
Map map = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
```

and then save it this way:

```
String image=json_user.getString(KEY_PHOTO);
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
map.put(KEY_PHOTO, bitmap);
```

And if you want to set the bitmap to an ImageView, you do the following.

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: My map is taking 2 values one type is string strin that is for name and for image its string bitmap so how can I use this two in combined way

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear about the question.  But now I think what you are asking is how to add two different types of object values to the same map, is that right?  In this case you would define the map to take a string as the Key and an Object as the value.  Then you can add strings or bitmap into the same map. [new Hashmap<String, Object>();]

Comment: Yes u got my point after doing what u said and passing bitmap in map its giving error that decoder-->>decode return false

Comment: {"tag":"contact","success":1,"error":0,"user":{"name":"aa","photo":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAW0AAAGQCAYAAABlDTHlAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU eJzsnXeYVdXV\/z9771Nunc7M0AcBQQUBQRBEQVGwd9TEDmqKienRRJOQmNeo0agxGmMssSco2HtD EQtSpIqAiPQyw\/R772l7\/\/44V95f3pi8eRMjId7P8\/A8MM8wZ5199qyz7tprfZegRIl\/A4wxQghh pk+frj7+2uTly42YNk3vSrtK"}}
01-14 19:36:38.251: D/dalvikvm(1296): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 
01-14 19:36:38.532: D/skia(1296): --- decoder->decode returned false

Comment: I would guess that there is some problems with the string you are decoding.  Are you sure it is correct?  You could try decoding it with an online Base64 decoder to verify you have a proper base64 string. http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Answer (score 0):

Update the adapter that your listview uses with a new entry for the string you needed to decode.

Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from your adapter after you've updated the data in it

Comment: Can you please post your adapter code and I'll explain it based on what you have?